# CGPoint does not conform to custom protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this custom protocol, named `DMPoint`.

```
protocol DMPoint {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var x: Double { get set }
    var y: Double { get set }
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    init(x: Double, y: Double)
}
```

I create an extension of the `CGPoint` which implements the `DMPoint`. By analysing the documentation for `CGPoint`, `CGPoint` should conform to `DMPoint` without any further implementation.

```
extension CGPoint: DMPoint { }
```

If I write this piece of code, I get the following error: `Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'DMPoint'`.

I have also used CGFloat for the data type used in DMPoint. It works for the CGPoint extension, but I also want to use this protocol for another classes that use `Double` instead of `CGFloat`, in which case those will also throw the same error. As of `Swift 5.5`, the compiler should be able to use to automatically convert CGFloat to Double and vice-versa.

I am using `Swift 5.7.2`. Is there any other way of making `CGPoint` conform to `DMPoint` other than using `CGFloat` instead of `Double` inside the `DMPoint` protocol?

Comment: I’m curious, what would you use this protocol for?

Comment: @Alexander This protocol is used for doing computations for both `CGPoint` and `GMSMapPoint` . For example, a method used for determining if a point is on a segment or not should only be written once. That is why I made both `GMSMapPoint` and `CGPoint` conform to this protocol.

Comment: Ah, cool! Aren't protocol extensions just so awesome? :D

Comment: @Alexander facts! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CoreFoundation, `CGPoint` uses `Double` (which is probably what you are seeing in the documentation), but in UIKit, for example, they are `CGFloat`.

Depending upon your use case, you might consider defining `DMPoint` to have an `associatedtype`, e.g.:

```swift
protocol DMPoint {
    associatedtype FloatType

    // MARK: - Properties

    var x: FloatType { get set }
    var y: FloatType { get set }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    init(x: FloatType, y: FloatType)
}

extension CGPoint: DMPoint { }
```

And if you need to have properties that always return `Double`, you can write an extension that defines distinct computed properties that return the `Double` values, but adding some constraint on the associated type, e.g.:

```swift
protocol DMPoint where FloatType: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    associatedtype FloatType

    // MARK: - Properties

    var x: FloatType { get set }
    var y: FloatType { get set }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    init(x: FloatType, y: FloatType)
}

extension CGPoint: DMPoint { }
```

And because of the magic of [SE-0307](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0307-allow-interchangeable-use-of-double-cgfloat-types.md), you can do things like:

```swift
let x: Double = point.x
```

Or, I guess you could write a protocol extension with default implementations to do this for you:

```swift
extension DMPoint {
    var doubleX: Double {
        get { Double(x) }
        set { x = FloatType(newValue) }
    }

    var doubleY: Double {
        get { Double(y) }
        set { y = FloatType(newValue) }
    }

    func xy() -> (Double, Double) {
        (doubleX, doubleY)
    }
}
```

And then you could do things like:

```swift
let x = point.doubleX
```

Or:

```swift
let (x, y) = point.xy()
```

---

The other alternative is to make `DMPoint` a concrete type, rather than a protocol, and, for example, give it a `cgPoint` computed property to bridge to `CGPoint`, e.g.:

```swift
struct DMPoint: Codable {
    // MARK: - Properties

    var x: Double
    var y: Double

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    init(x: Double, y: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

    init(cgPoint: CGPoint) {
        x = Double(cgPoint.x)
        y = Double(cgPoint.y)
    }

    var cgPoint: CGPoint {
        get { CGPoint(x: x, y: y) }
        set { x = Double(newValue.x); y = Double(newValue.y) }
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    var dmPoint: DMPoint {
        DMPoint(cgPoint: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your in depth explanation, @Rob! I changed my protocol definition to this, as it suited my code the best: `protocol DMPoint where FloatType: BinaryFloatingPoint { .... }`.